# Finding $f^{(12)}(0)$ with $f(x)=\log(e^{x^4}-2x^8)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Here's how I proceeded:

We have $f(x)=x^4+\log\left(1-2x^8e^{-x^4}\right),$ hence for all $x$ such that $-1\le2x^8e^{-x^4}<1$ the following holds: 
\begin{align} f(x)=x^4+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(-2x^8e^{-x^4}\right)^n&=x^4-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\left(2x^8e^{-x^4}\right)^n \\&=x^4-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\left(\dfrac{2x^8}{1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{4k}/k!}\right)^n\\&=x^4-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\left(2x^8\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{4k}}{k!}\right)^j\right)^n\\&=x^4-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\left(2x^8-2x^{12}+x^{16}+\sum_{k=5}^\infty a_kx^{4k}\right)^n\\&=x^4-2x^8+2x^{12}-5x^{16}+\sum_{k=5}^\infty b_k x^{4k},
\end{align}where $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ are suitable sequences of real numbers. Differentiating term by term, we conclude $f^{(12)}(0)=2(12)! \ .$ Am I correct? Is this the fastest approach, generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct.

A faster approach comes from $e^{-x^4}=1-x^4+O(x^8)$ and $\log(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$, that grant:
$$ [x^{12}]\log(1-2x^8 e^{-x^4}) = [x^{12}]\log(1-2x^8+2x^{12}) = [x^{12}](-2x^8+2x^{12})=\color{red}{2}.$$

Comment: Yeah, we just need to know the coefficient of the twelfth power in the series expansion. Thank you.